# Rabbitmq server working

Tags: python, rabbitmq

suppose i have a producer on rabbitmq server which will generate a random number and pass it to the consumer. Consumer will receive all the random-numbers from producer. If i will kill my consumer process, what will producer do in this situation? whether it will continuously generate the number and when ever the consumer(client) will come up it will start sending again all the numbers generated by producer or some thing else...

Answer (score 1):

To fully embrace the functionality you need to understand how the rabbitmq broker works with exchanges. I believe this will solve your problem.

Instead of sending to a single queue you will create an exchange. The producer sends to the exchange. In this state with no queues at this point the messages will be discarded. You will then need to create a queue in order for a consumer to receive the messages. The consumer will create the queue and bind it to the exchange. At that point the queue will receive messages and deliver them to the consumer.

In your case you will probably use a fanout exchange so that you do not need to worry about binding and routing keys. But you should also set you queue to be autodelete. That will ensure that when the consumer goes down the queue will be deleted. And hence the producer, unaffected by this, will continue to send messages to the exchange that are discarded until the queue is reconnected.

Answer (score 1):

For now I'm going to assume you have a topic exchange. If there is a queue and its bound to the same exchange and routing key (or dotted prefix) of the producer, the queue will build up the messages whether there is a consumer there or not... *for the most part*.

> The core idea in the messaging model in RabbitMQ is that the producer
>   never sends any messages directly to a queue. Actually, quite often
>   the producer doesn't even know if a message will be delivered to any
>   queue at all.
>   -- http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html

If the queue does not exist the message gets discarded. If the queue does exist (ie its durable) there are configurations that you can make on the queue and/or message that will make it so your messages have a TTL or time to live: (http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html and http://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html). You might also want to look into and understand queue durability and auto-delete. I highly recommend you look at the AMQP quick reference also as you can figure out what you want from that: http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html . You'll have to convert the pseudo code to your library or client.

Basically it all boils down to what type of exchange and the configuration of the queue and message.

Answer (score 0):

The q in rabbit mq stands for queue. This means that all messages placed in the queue, in your case the producers random numbers, will remain in the queue until someone comes to get them.